# How do you debug on breakpoints in swift on xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I face trouble using po/p command in xcode using swift. It doesn't work always and gives error most of the time. Also its response is not useful most of the time. For example, when i type "po user" it gives  instead of its details and items which i could expand while using objective-c

How do you debug any breakpoint? Are there any great external tools or alternatives available for this?

Comment: `po` will work in swift

Comment: it doesn't work always.. It gives error most of the time. Although it's working now, but when i type "po user" it gives <User: 0x7fa11bcaa100> instead of its details and items which i could expand while using objective-c

Answer (score 4):

`po` command works in swift too

```
po yourvariable.description
po yourvariable.debugDescription
```

or

```
po print(yourvariable)
```

Comment: it doesn't work always.. It gives error most of the time. Although it's working now, but when i type "po user" it gives <User: 0x7fa11bcaa100> instead of its details and items which i could expand while using objective-c

Comment: @avnishkgaur the user is may be an object you have to catch values from it like user.name etc. Try to check it.

Comment: I am getting this error when i log a variable: 
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'xxxxxx' from AST context:
*some pod files are mentioned*
A fatal parse error has occurred.  LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with Xcode 6 to 7.1.1. Here is a workaround until the gets bug fixed:

Use the p command instead. If this doesnt work then do "step into" before you type the p command.

```
p yourvariable.yourparameter
```

Reference this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841849/4144106