# lldb debugger gives wrong answer?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

I am new to Xcode and don't have experience using lldb the debugging tool. I am following the tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) from Apple. I noticed that lldb tool gives me some opposite info about a variable I am hovering my mouse over. How does this happen?

[image: Screen shot 2]

Comment: Your mouse is hovered on line `127` where it was still `false`. Then you stepped to `128` and did `po` where it's already true

Comment: @janusbalatbat I uploaded another screen shot. The variable `isPresentingInAddMode` is evaluated false therefore the block between line 128 and 129 is not entered. lldb says the boolean is true.

Comment: Sometimes happens that the GUI doesn’t get updated values. But judging from the breakpoint line i’d surpridingly trust the one hovered. Can you reproduce it also after usual deep-cash-clean and xcode restart?

Comment: @jalone: Same thing happens after I cleaned the build folder, deleted DerivedData folder, restarted XCode and computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have some interest findings. I am posting them here for the community because I haven't seen any similar answers on SO. However it is more like a clue, not really an "answer" per se.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841849/3207158) SO answer, I played a little more with lldb. Here is one thing I tried:

```
let v1: Int? = nil
let v2 = (v1 is String)
let v3 = (v1 is Int?)
let v4 = (v1 is Int)
```

and then I did `p` and `po` on them...

```
|---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|         |    v1    |    v2    |    v3    |    v4    |
|    p    |   nil    |   false  |   true   |   false  |
|    po   |   nil    |   true   |   true   |   true   |
|---------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

I can definitely relate this experiment to the original situation I had where `presentingViewController` is also nil. It looks like the command `po`, that prints the description of an object, will display `true` to "any OptionalVariable `is` any type" statements.

I am still researching more on this and looking for official documentations...

Comment: I can't reproduce the results of your experiment with the Xcode 10 beta.  If I put your snippet in a .swift file  as the body of a () -> Void function, and stop AFTER all the assignments have been run, then `po` & `p` return consistent and correct results.  Can you present a complete example?  Also, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @JimIngham. I did reproduce the same result after putting the code ina separate ()->Void function. I am using XCode 9.2 with Swift 4.0