# Xcode Console "po" error: expression failed to parse

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My Xcode cannot `po` anything suddenly.

For example:

```
po param

error: expression failed to parse:
error: Couldn't realize type of self.
```

Every time I use `po` to print something in the console, it will show the errors above. This started happening one month ago.

Comment: Does it do that in all projects on all breakpoints or only in a specific place in a particular project? If you try `p` or `expr` instead of `po`, does it work?

Comment: same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: I click right button to select ```print``` and solve this problem... even thought it does not good as using ```po```

Comment: See my answer to this related question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831028/1461050

Comment: None of these "solutions" work when attempting to print the app's debugDescription (for XCUITest). Dead in the water here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

well, you could click right button and choose "print..." at console.

Comment: I upgrade my Xcode, 'po' works again.

Answer (score 5):

I know this does not fix the problem, but meanwhile you can use `v param` to achieve the expected result.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60064468/2347811

Comment: thanks, but still not working, is this caused by updated XCode?

Comment: I found a solution, click right button and select "print"... well, it is not good as ```po``` but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is easy solution:
Change `Debug information Format` for `Debug` to "`DWARF`" in `Build Settings`. It should be done for both `TARGETS` AND `PROJECT`.
[image]

Change it back to "`DWARF with DSYM File`" when upload application on Appstore.

Answer (score 1):

for my case i just changed build configuration to debug build mode .

edit scheme -> Run -> info -> build configuration -> select Debug

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure this out forever. Finally decided to compare my projects settings to a project where I know the `po` command worked.

That's when I noticed this difference...

In your Target > Build Rules > Apple Clang - Code Generation > Optimization Level > Debug must be set to None [-O0], or the debugger might not work. Someone had set it to Fast (face palm).

Life Saver!!!

[Screenshot of Target Build Rule settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui9nB.png)

[Screenshot of description of different Optimization levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cJ2G.png)